# How Can I Add Value to Save / Apply Changes with JToolBarHelper

Tags: php, forms, joomla, request, hidden

I have an edit view which need to pass a hidden value through the form in a Joomla 2.5 component.  Where would I go about adding this form value?

Here is my attempt (that is not working):

In the `../admin/models/forms/componentview.xml` file I have added the following field:

```
    <field
    name="variableToPassBackToMainView"
    type="hidden"
    value="1"
    />
```

My thought was that by adding this hidden field to the model form, when it was saved then the `variableToPassBackToMainView` would be picked up by the new view.  The view has the following variable definition to retrieve the value:

```
$variableToPassBackToMainView = $_REQUEST["variableToPassBackToMainView"];
```

---

Updated Info:

Joomla 2.5 Component

Here is the `edit.php`

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
JHtml::_('behavior.tooltip');
JHtml::_('behavior.formvalidation');
    $params = $this->form->getFieldsets('params');

?>
    <form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_mycomponent&layout=edit&id='.(int) $this->item->id); ?>" method="post" name="adminForm" id="mycomponent-form" class="form-validate">
<div class="width-60 fltlft">
    <fieldset class="adminform">
        <legend><?php echo JText::_( 'COM_MYCOMPONENT_DETAILS' ); ?></legend>
        <ul class="adminformlist">
<?php foreach($this->form->getFieldset('componenttitledetails') as $field): ?>
            <li><?php echo $field->label;echo $field->input;?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
</div>

<div class="width-40 fltrt">
    <?php echo JHtml::_('sliders.start', 'mycomponent-slider'); ?>

<?php foreach ($params as $name => $fieldset): ?>
    <?php echo JHtml::_('sliders.panel', JText::_($fieldset->label), $name.'-params');?>
<?php if (isset($fieldset->description) && trim($fieldset->description)): ?>
    <p class="tip"><?php echo $this->escape(JText::_($fieldset->description));?></p>
<?php endif;?>
    <fieldset class="panelform" >
        <ul class="adminformlist">
<?php foreach ($this->form->getFieldset($name) as $field) : ?>
            <li><?php echo $field->label; ?><?php echo $field->input; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
<?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php echo JHtml::_('sliders.end'); ?>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="componentview.edit" />
    <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: The field would still have to be displayed when you display the form. What is the code that displays all the form items when the page loads?

Comment: I have tried adding `<input type="hidden" name="variableToPassBackToMainView" value="1" />` to the `edit.php` view, but it is still not pulling through.  Is that where you are referencing?

Comment: Kind of. I'm guessing there are other fields that are defined in `componentview.xml` that actually get displayed on the field. How are those getting displayed? Also, is this Joomla 3 or 2.5?

Comment: Just getting back to this today.  Yes, there are other fields displayed.  I will edit the question to show those field and explain how they are displayed.  This is a joomla 2.5 component.

Comment: I'm much more interested in the `edit.php` file actually.

Comment: Okay I have just updated the info on the question with the `edit.php` details.

Comment: @DavidFritsch any ideas from the update?